# Get date when the process was started in epoch seconds

Tags: bash, timestamps, time

I need to get the date when a particular process was started by PID.

For this purpose, I use:

```
stat -c %y /proc/PID
```

In the output, I get the date in the following format:

```
2021-07-04 11:00:20.352976946 +0300'
```

But I need it in seconds since the epoch.

Is it possible somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know about the on-system documentation? `man stat` for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `%Y` instead of `%y`.

```bsh
stat -c %Y /proc/28
1626244631
```

From `man stat`:

> `%Y`
> time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch